# What is the direct translation of 深さ不明 or Fuka-sa Fumei?

Tags: translation

I do not know very much about the language and am doing research for a story that I am writing. I intend to use Fuka-sa Fumei as the name of a submarine. I apologize if I'm breaking any rules or codes of conduct for this site. Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can give.

Comment: ... https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628

Comment: We do not cover translation questions (for the literal meaning you can try a machine translation). However, I would advise you to revise your question, mentioning how you came up with the name 深さ不明. I think it should be fine to ask if there are Japanese naming conventions for naval vessels and whether 深さ不明 could be an appropriate name for a submarine.

Comment: ^ そうですね・・ 「深さ不明」 would be pretty weird as a name of a submarine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct translation is **unknown depths**.

> - 深さ -> depth
> - 不明 -> unknown

**Edited**
...

> The depth is unknown in the sense "you don't know how deep something is".

Comment: `unknown depths` って、「未知の海底」とか「未知の深淵」って意味になりますよね。「深さ不明」は、「深さが不明だ」"The depth is unknown (in the sense 'you don't know how deep something is')." ってちゃんと説明しないと誤解を招きませんか？

Comment: @Chocolate ああ、確かにそうですね。ご指摘ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

"深さ不明" implies we don't know how deep the sea under the ground level is if you are talking about the depth of the sea. If your submarine intends to go unexplored depth of the sea like James Cameron's submarine"Deepsea", "未到達の深さ" can be close.　Probably abyss still works for the translation, too.